# Cycle through open windows in C# using ALT+TAB/ESC and have the current window in focus and forced to be maximized (if already minimized to taskbar)?

Tags: c#, windows, keypress

I am writing a small application to automatically rotate through open windows on Windows 7/8.1/10 PC's. I have written the majority of the code and it is working well except I cannot figure out or find out what key presses to use to cycle through open applications.

I have tried `SendKeys.Send("%{Tab 2}");` but this seems to only actually press the TAB button once as it keeps switching between the same two windows (even though more are open).

I have tried `SendKeys.Send("%+{Esc}");` but this doesn't maximize windows that are minimized to the taskbar. It will effectively cycle through each open windows and bring them into focus (as evident by watching the white semi-transparent overlay on the taskbar item) but it won't show them on screen - I'm assuming because they started minimized. Only the maximized ones will show on screen when it's their turn.

Can anyone please assist? I'm sure it's a simple fix of maximizing the window it cycles to but I'm unsure how to implement this.

I haven't included the code of the entire application as I don't think it is relevant. If you do require it please let me know and I will add it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Really is no one able to help with something like this?

Comment: Ok someone can delete this post now - obviously no one is capable of assisting unfortunately.